# In Azure B2C how to force password reset when the user does the first login (Custom Policy)

Tags: azure, azure-ad-b2c, azure-ad-b2c-custom-policy

I am trying to find how I can make the a new user whose account was created via MS Graph API to force reset his password the first time he logins with the temporary password. After resetting the password I also want to ask him to input his Surname , Given Name & Display Name.

Also, in the same user flow whenever for example (SignUp/SignIn) - if the user is old he can login using his usual password directly and would not be asked to provide any profile details.

And, I want this whole process to one single user journey,

- Ask to Reset password if new user which account created by graph api, then in the same ui ask for display name, given name & last name and then, save
- Login if old user
- Signup if new user want to signup himself
- forget password link working if he want to reset the password himself or forgets it

I am really trying to understand the orchestration steps and everything to make this happen but somehow I am yet to find any solution.

I am following : [force password reset first logon sample](https://github.com/amanmcse/samples/blob/master/policies/force-password-reset-first-logon/TrustFrameworkExtensions.xml)

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
  TenantId="sundayfunday.onmicrosoft.com" 
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_Demo_TrustFrameworkExtensions_SSPR" 
  PublicPolicyUri="http://sundayfunday.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_Demo_TrustFrameworkExtensions_SSPR">

  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>sundayfunday.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_TrustFrameworkExtensions</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>
  <BuildingBlocks>
    <ClaimsSchema>
      <ClaimType Id="isForgotPassword">
        <DisplayName>Indicates whether the user selected Forgot Password</DisplayName>
        <DataType>boolean</DataType>
        <AdminHelpText></AdminHelpText>
      </ClaimType>
    </ClaimsSchema>
  </BuildingBlocks>

  <ClaimsProviders>
    <ClaimsProvider>
      <DisplayName>Local Account</DisplayName>
      <TechnicalProfiles>

        <!-- Set the isForgotPassword to true-->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="ForgotPassword">
          <DisplayName>Forgot your password?</DisplayName>
          <Protocol Name="Proprietary" Handler="Web.TPEngine.Providers.ClaimsTransformationProtocolProvider, Web.TPEngine, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=null" />
          <OutputClaims>
            <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="isForgotPassword" DefaultValue="true" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" />
          </OutputClaims>
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <!-- Update the sign-up or sign-in page with forgot password link target ClaimsExchange -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email">
          <Metadata>
            <Item Key="setting.forgotPasswordLinkOverride">ForgotPasswordExchange</Item>
          </Metadata>
        </TechnicalProfile>

        <!-- Adding the required session manager -->
        <TechnicalProfile Id="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId">
          <UseTechnicalProfileForSessionManagement ReferenceId="SM-AAD" />
        </TechnicalProfile>

      </TechnicalProfiles>
    </ClaimsProvider>
  </ClaimsProviders>

  <UserJourneys>

    <UserJourney Id="SignUpOrSignIn-Custom">
      <OrchestrationSteps>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="CombinedSignInAndSignUp" ContentDefinitionReferenceId="api.signuporsignin">
          <ClaimsProviderSelections>
            <!-- <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="FacebookExchange" /> -->
            <ClaimsProviderSelection ValidationClaimsExchangeId="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" />
            <ClaimsProviderSelection TargetClaimsExchangeId="ForgotPasswordExchange" />
          </ClaimsProviderSelections>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="LocalAccountSigninEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-LocalAccountSignin-Email" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Check if the user has selected to sign in using one of the social providers -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <!-- <ClaimsExchange Id="FacebookExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="Facebook-OAUTH" /> -->
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SignUpWithLogonEmailExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountSignUpWithLogonEmail" />
            <ClaimsExchange Id="ForgotPasswordExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="ForgotPassword" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="3" Type="InvokeSubJourney">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="false">
              <Value>isForgotPassword</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <JourneyList>
            <Candidate SubJourneyReferenceId="PasswordReset" />
          </JourneyList>
        </OrchestrationStep>


        <!-- Show self-asserted page only if the directory does not have the user account already (i.e. we do not have an objectId). 
          This can only happen when authentication happened using a social IDP. If local account was created or authentication done
          using ESTS in step 2, then an user account must exist in the directory by this time. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="4" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="SelfAsserted-Social" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="SelfAsserted-Social" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- This step reads any user attributes that we may not have received when authenticating using ESTS so they can be sent 
          in the token. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="5" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimEquals" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>authenticationSource</Value>
              <Value>socialIdpAuthentication</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserReadWithObjectId" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserReadUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
        <!-- The previous step (SelfAsserted-Social) could have been skipped if there were no attributes to collect 
             from the user. So, in that case, create the user in the directory if one does not already exist 
             (verified using objectId which would be set from the last step if account was created in the directory. -->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="6" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <Preconditions>
            <Precondition Type="ClaimsExist" ExecuteActionsIf="true">
              <Value>objectId</Value>
              <Action>SkipThisOrchestrationStep</Action>
            </Precondition>
          </Preconditions>
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="AADUserWrite" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <OrchestrationStep Order="7" Type="SendClaims" CpimIssuerTechnicalProfileReferenceId="JwtIssuer" />

      </OrchestrationSteps>
      <ClientDefinition ReferenceId="DefaultWeb" />
    </UserJourney>
  </UserJourneys>
  <SubJourneys>
    <SubJourney Id="PasswordReset" Type="Call">
      <OrchestrationSteps>
        <!-- Validate user's email address. Run this step only when user resets the password-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="1" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="PasswordResetUsingEmailAddressExchange" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountDiscoveryUsingEmailAddress" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>

        <!-- Collect and persist a new password. Run this step only when user resets the password-->
        <OrchestrationStep Order="2" Type="ClaimsExchange">
          <ClaimsExchanges>
            <ClaimsExchange Id="NewCredentials" TechnicalProfileReferenceId="LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId" />
          </ClaimsExchanges>
        </OrchestrationStep>
      </OrchestrationSteps>
    </SubJourney>
  </SubJourneys>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<TrustFrameworkPolicy xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/online/cpim/schemas/2013/06" PolicySchemaVersion="0.3.0.0" 
  TenantId="sundayfunday.onmicrosoft.com" 
  PolicyId="B2C_1A_Demo_SignUp_SignIn_SSPR" 
  PublicPolicyUri="http://sundayfunday.onmicrosoft.com/B2C_1A_Demo_SignUp_SignIn_SSPR">

  <BasePolicy>
    <TenantId>sundayfunday.onmicrosoft.com</TenantId>
    <PolicyId>B2C_1A_Demo_TrustFrameworkExtensions_SSPR</PolicyId>
  </BasePolicy>

  <RelyingParty>
    <DefaultUserJourney ReferenceId="SignUpOrSignIn-Custom" />
    <TechnicalProfile Id="PolicyProfile">
      <DisplayName>PolicyProfile</DisplayName>
      <Protocol Name="OpenIdConnect" />
      <OutputClaims>
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="email" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="objectId" PartnerClaimType="sub" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="identityProvider" />
        <OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="tenantId" AlwaysUseDefaultValue="true" DefaultValue="{Policy:TenantObjectId}" />
      </OutputClaims>
      <SubjectNamingInfo ClaimType="sub" />
    </TechnicalProfile>
  </RelyingParty>
</TrustFrameworkPolicy>
```

currently my forget password link is also not working and I am unable to how to ask user for last name , first name, display name in the same password reset flow page (or the next page after that) user flow of what I am trying to create:

[image]

download the policy i am working with:

[image]

Also, when I try to use the [embedded password reset to make the reset button working](https://github.com/azure-ad-b2c/samples/tree/master/policies/embedded-password-reset)

it gives some error while trying to add (**Facebook-Auth**) and some **AlternativeSecurityId** related validation error, maybe that is because I am using the locaaccounts social starter packer rather than the socialandlocalaccounts as I do not want any social identity provider.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't know who the user is until they log in so they have to do that before you can decide if they are a new user or not.

When a user is created in B2C, a "newUser" attribute is set. I don't know if that applies when a user is created by Graph, but if not, also create an extension attribute, and you can check for that.

Remove all the Facebook references from the embedded password sample.

For the extra fields. add another self-asserted Technical Profile in the user journey after the change password. Use "SelfAsserted-Social" as an example.

There's an example of "Change Password" [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory-b2c/add-password-change-policy?pivots=b2c-custom-policy).

**Update**

The reason for the Facebook error is that you also have to remove the steps in the user journey like "AAD-UserReadUsingAlternativeSecurityId-NoError" i.e. anything that mentions "AlternativeSecurityId".

**Update 2**

You can use "SelfAsserted-Social" in the base pretty much as is.

In the password reset policy, add this as a step after "LocalAccountWritePasswordUsingObjectId".

The output fields in "SelfAsserted-Social" e.g.

```
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="displayName"/>
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="givenName"/>
<OutputClaim ClaimTypeReferenceId="surname"/>
```

are the fields you want the user to enter.

Change "AAD-UserWriteUsingAlternativeSecurityId" to "AAD-UserWriteProfileUsingObjectId".

Comment: Yes, So when the user login (I already or the system already has information if he is new or not) - if he is new user and signing in for the first time it should prompt the user to reset password. For that I have used the **extension_mustRequirePassword** custom attribute claim type. The problem I am currently facing is that I have to add the self assestered technical profile in the user journey as you have mentioned to ask user to input the displayName, firstName, lastName (I am unable to understand how to do that) and also the forget password link not working.

Comment: Also, I have removed the facebook references from the embedded password sample but still it's not working and it gives the **AlternativeSecurityId-NoError** some type of error.